# Moving code from theme header to functions.php

Tags: php, functions, multisite, redirect, headers

Just wanted some advice in relation to adding some custom code to my wordpress site. I am using `geoip` to check a users country code and redirect them to the relevant site when they land on my homepage.

Currently I include this block of `php` code at the very top of my themes `header.php` file. However I'm not sure that is the best way to go about it, would it be better off in the `functions.php` and if so is there a `hook` I can use to call this code when the homepage is about to be loaded and redirect accordingly?

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__) . "/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if ($url === "/") {
    //If IE go to /ie
    if ($country_code === "IE") {
        header("Location: http://www.wpmultisite.com/ie");
        die();
    }//If GB go to /uk
    else if ($country_code === "GB") {
        header("Location: http://www.wpmultisite.com/uk");
        die();
    }
}
```

I should point out I'm trying to set up a network of sites using the `Wordpress Multisite` functionality.

Many thanks in advance for any of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend moving this to a plugin, rather than doing it in the theme, and then activating it on the main site. The rule that I follow is that if it's going to affect the *look*, it goes in the theme; if it's affecting *functionality*, then it goes in a plugin. This, to my mind, is a functional thing.

`wp-content/plugins/my-ms-redirector/my-ms-redirector.php`:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My MS Redirector
Description: Redirects to /ie, /uk, etc based on geoip
*/

add_action( 'init', 'wpse206906_redirector' );

function wpse206906_redirector() {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    require_once("geoip.inc");
    $gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__) . "/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    geoip_close($gi);
    if ($url === "/") {
        //If IE go to /ie
        if ($country_code === "IE") {
            wp_redirect( 'http://www.wpmultisite.com/ie' ) ;
            exit();
        }//If GB go to /uk
        if ($country_code === "GB") {
            wp_redirect( 'http://www.wpmultisite.com/uk' );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

### References

- [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)
- [`init` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)

(I know that `die()` and `exit()` are functionally identical, but I tend to use `exit()` when I just want to end PHP execution, and `die()` when I want to throw an error. It's a personal preference.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use this code as early as you can. I personally would give this task to the webserver and/or Varnish or similar great pieces of software.

In case of WordPress, you could either prepend `/index.php` with this, or attach to one of the most early hooks there are, like `muplugins_loaded`, `plugins_loaded`, `setup_theme` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_head','language_redirect');

function language_redirect() {


require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__) . "/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if (is_front_page()) {
    //If IE go to /ie
    if ($country_code === "IE") {
        header("Location: http://www.wpmultisite.com/ie");
        die();
    }//If GB go to /uk
    else if ($country_code === "GB") {
        header("Location: http://www.wpmultisite.com/uk");
        die();
    }
}

}
```